# "Create Enterprise Geodatabase" errors

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, esri-geodatabase, spatial-database

I am trying to use " Create Enterprise Geodatabase" option in arcmap 10.1:

I am getting two following errors:

> You must copy the latest ST_GEOMETRY and dependent libraries to the PostgreSQL software location. Refer to the ArcGIS help topics for more details.

and

> Connected RDBMS instance is not setup for Esri spatial type configuration.
>   Failed to execute

I have put `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\DatabaseSupport\PostgreSQL\Linux64\st_geometry.so` in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.2` directory.

Comment: You mention two errors and then ask 2-3 questions.  To better fit our Q&A format, my recommendation is to edit your question to focus on what is most important for you to know first.  I suspect that is encapsulated in your last paragraph.  Once you know that, you'll be better placed to decide whether the errors remain relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the [Esri step-by-step tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p000000t4000000) on how to setup the PostgreSQL and ArcGIS?

I have also had a discussion with Esri analysts [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/80398-Cannot-find-DBMS-Support-files-ArcGIS-10.1-SP1-amp-PostgreSQL-9.1.3), worth checking

Comment: very helpful conversation on the link on Esri; now the error changed to: "Geodatabase must be enabled as geodatabase admin user.Failed to execute " What is this error about? Thanks

Comment: John, do you get the error while creating a geodatabase? It seems as you need to enable a database as geodatabase, but it seems to be possible only when you have created one... http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000r8000000

Answer (score 3):

You need to play close attention to version numbers when installing
support libraries.  You are placing the Esri PostgreSQL 9.0 library
in PG 9.2 -- this will not work. In fact, [PostgreSQL 9.2 support was
not introduced until ArcGIS 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#/PostgreSQL_Database_Requirements/015100000075000000/), so [there isn't any way to connect
an ArcGIS 10.1 client to PG 9.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#/PostgreSQL_Database_Requirements/015100000075000000/).